# How to dynamically add environment variables to the running shell when using the Visual Studio debugger and a launch settings.json profile?

Tags: visual-studio, environment-variables, visual-studio-debugging

I would like to have 2 debug profiles in my launchSettngs.json file (1 for Kestrel and 1 for Docker).

In both cases, I want to pass environment variables to the application.

I want the variables set at the process level to avoid conflicts between apps. So, no user or machine level variables.

I do not want to supply the values in the `environmentVariables` section of the launchSettings.json file because:

- I do not want these values checked into source control
- I don't really want these values even persisted to disk
- These values exist in a cloud vault and should be retrieved dynamically prior to execution of the application based on the authentication of the current developer.

I also do not want the code to have to fetch the environment variables from the vault itself. I want the code to be agnostic. In production, the infrastructure should supply the values to the container. So, locally, the dev tooling should supply the values to the app.

And, of course, I want to still be able to F5 in Visual Studio and use the debugger.

Ideally, I could specify a pre-run script in my launchSettings.json file that would go get the values from the vault and setup the env vars for the shell that Visual Studio is launching.

Is there a way to do such a thing? If so, how?

If it matters, I can use VS2022 and .Net 6.

Comment: I too am interested in this. I travel a lot and would like a launch.json script which would pull my local IP address so I can examine traffic between my locally running application.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but for what it's worth, I use DotNetEnv library for this https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetEnv

This **does not work** for things you need during process creation, e.g. CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING, CORECLR_PROFILER, etc. But for everything else, it works really well.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar. I wrote a dotnet tool that gets data from AWS parameter store and can either set the in process variables or write the env file. And I set the entry point of the container to a script that first runs the dotnet tool and then the service.